# Qt Console Application with optional GUI

Tags: qt, console, qt4, qt5

I have written a console application for my server. It works very well, I can start it over the terminal and all is okay.
For desktop environments it would be very nice, to set a flag in the settings.ini file of the program to open a MainWindow to show some information of the running console application. The console in the background can be left open. All I need is a window and some SINGAL/SLOTS between the main application running in console and the MainWindow.

How to realize this? I figured out, I have to handle with QApplication and QCoreApplication right?

Comment: If you want to configure GUI or not with an .ini file, it means your program is already capable of doing both console and GUI so it uses a QApplication and not a QCoreApplication, it already has all the GUI code compiled and linked but just never create the MainWindow. Or you make 2 different binaries and you don't need the .ini file, it's up to the user to choose which program he wants. In any case you always have only 1 QApplication (or QCoreApplication) in your program, you don't use both at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put this line to your pro file:

```
CONFIG += console
```

In *Qt5.x from Win7 to Win10* you could do **something like this**:

```
//includes
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDir>
#include <QSettings>

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

//
// Add to project file:
// CONFIG += console
//
```

The server:

```
//Here we have the Server class able to send signals
//Server will be used in main.cpp for console
//and/or in MainWindow to handle the signals
class Server : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Server( QObject *parent = 0 ) : QObject( parent )
    {
        //do server stuff
        //this->setName( "Test" );
        //std::cout << this->getName( ) << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "Enter URL: << std::endl;
        //std::string url;
        //std::cin >> url;
        //_url = QString::fromStdString( url );
        //emit finished();
    }

signals:
    void finished( );

private:
    QString _url;

};
```

The MainWindow:

```
//Here is the MainWindow using Server
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow( QWidget *parent = 0 ) : QMainWindow()
    {
        server = new Server( this ); //use server in hybrid mode (console and gui)
        connect( server, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(close()) ); //establish connection
    }

private:
    Server *server;

};
```

The main:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    QString iniPath = QFileInfo( QDir::fromNativeSeparators(argv[0]) ).absolutePath(); //get the current dir
    QSettings settings( iniPath+"/settings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat ); //open ini
    bool gui = settings.value( "gui", false ).toBool(); //read ini
    if( gui ) //decide
    {
    #if defined( Q_OS_WIN )
        // hide console window, but not in your case
        // ::ShowWindow( ::GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE );
    #endif
        //std::cout will print to the console in the bg like you wished
        QApplication a( argc, argv );
        MainWindow *w = new MainWindow;
        w->show();
        int e = a.exec();
        delete w; //needed to execute deconstructor
        exit( e ); //needed to exit the hidden console
        return e;
    }
    else
    {
        QCoreApplication a( argc, argv );
        Server *instance = new Server; //use server in console only
        exit( 0 );
        return a.exec();
    }
}
```

---

---

I tried it also **without** the "CONFIG += console", but then you need to redirect the streams and create the console on your own:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) || AllocConsole()){
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
}
#endif
```

**BUT** this only works if you start it through a debugger, otherwise all inputs are directed towards the system too. Means, if you type a name via std::cin the system tries to execute the name as a command. (very strange)

*Two other warnings* to this attempt would be, that you can't use ::FreeConsole() it won't close it and if you start it through a console the app won't close.

---

---

Last there is a [Qt help section in QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#details) to this topic. I tried the example there with an application and it **doesn't work for the GUI**, it stucked somewhere in an endless loop and the GUI won't be rendered or it simply crashes:

```
QCoreApplication* createApplication(int &argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        if (!qstrcmp(argv[i], "-no-gui"))
            return new QCoreApplication(argc, argv);
    return new QApplication(argc, argv);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer<QCoreApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));

    if (qobject_cast<QApplication *>(app.data())) {
       // start GUI version...
    } else {
       // start non-GUI version...
    }

    return app->exec();
}
```

---

---

So if you are using Windows and Qt simply use the console option, hide the console if you need the GUI and close it via exit.